# ID values in REST-style URLs

Tags: web-services, rest, http, url

If my application has more than one way to identify a resource, say for example a globally unique identifier, and also compound key of more human-friendly values, which is considered preferable?

As an example:

> - https://localhost:12345/api/customer/{customerId:int}/product/{productSku}
> - https://localhost:12345/api/customer/732/product/46
> - https://localhost:12345/api/customer/abc-spares-ltd/product/CF31-APB

as opposed to:

> - https://localhost:12345/api/product/{productGlobalId:Guid}
> - https://localhost:12345/api/product/B51B6E8A-B68E-4FD0-9FC2-BAA682FAFB14

this is a possibility, but seems pointless:

> - https://localhost:12345/api/customer/{customerId:int}/product/{productGlobalId:Guid}
> - https://localhost:12345/api/customer/81C51258-DDDD-4815-A207-37ED735D1AEA/product/B51B6E8A-B68E-4FD0-9FC2-BAA682FAFB14

Aside from one being less readable in this case (the more direct one could easily have been a unique integer in the system), what would the reasoning be behind the choice? Should one implement both, or should there only be one URL for a given resource?

Some things I think have a bearing on it:

- The second option will require less translation between the "friendly" ID values and internal globally-unique values.
- In SQL databases, using the primary key means not having to define further indexes (which have a hit on insert/updates).
- In NoSQL databases, "get-by-ID" is typical, and queries may even return eventually-consistent data if the database system's "primary key" equivalent isn't used, or some translation may be required.
- Is there a relationship between the two things (in this example there is, but because of the existence of a guid ID, it's not strictly necessary to find a product as a subset of a set.
- Would DDD-style aggregate design inform the decision? For example, a Product would NOT be part of the Customer aggregate, even though in practical terms there is a relationship (e.g. one customer would not "see" another customer's products).
- If it was in theory possible for the "SKU" to be modified for a product, then the URL might actually end up pointing to a different resource. With an immutable "internal" identifier this would not be possible (you'd probably implement as a 404 with a soft-delete, and create a whole new product).

Comment: Not sure why API endpoints should be *human-friendly* as it's a *programming interface*, so I would better stick to `/customer/732/product/46`.

Answer (score 3):

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your URI.

The *point* of a REST API (in HTTP) is to make your domain work like a website.  So when you are thinking about *resources*, you should be thinking about what your representations mean from the outside, not how look on the inside (ie, not your current implementation).

That is to say, you should be able to switch between using an RDBMS and a no-sql Document store without changing the API.  Your API exposes integration resources, so that clients are shielded from your implementation choices.  Jim Webber's [Domain Driven Design for RESTful Systems](https://yow.eventer.com/events/1004/talks/1047) expands on this point.

> Aside from one being less readable in this case (the more direct one could easily have been a unique integer in the system), what would the reasoning be behind the choice?

You should be choosing spellings that are consistent with [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (hierarchy in the path, non hierarchical elements in the query string, fragments for secondary resources included within a primary).

[Cool URI Don't Change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI) -- the spellings that you use should be motivated by keeping URI stable over time (which includes decoupling them from an implementation that may evolve over time).

You should be choosing spellings that are human readable -- the machines consumers *don't care*, because they just follow links or fill in templates (assuming that your API includes hypermedia affordances).

Example: which do you have bookmarked?  Google, or 216.58.209.164 ?

> Should one implement both, or should there only be one URL for a given resource?

There's always going to be one URI per resource -- that's kind of baked into the definition.  That said, you may have many resources that share the same representation at any given moment in time.

Fielding used this example in [his thesis](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1).

> For example, the "authors' preferred version" of an academic paper is a mapping whose value changes over time, whereas a mapping to "the paper published in the proceedings of conference X" is static. These are two distinct resources, even if they both map to the same value at some point in time. The distinction is necessary so that both resources can be identified and referenced independently. A similar example from software engineering is the separate identification of a version-controlled source code file when referring to the "latest revision", "revision number 1.2.7", or "revision included with the Orange release."

Looking at your additional thoughts...

> Would DDD-style aggregate design inform the decision? For example, a Product would NOT be part of the Customer aggregate, even though in practical terms there is a relationship (e.g. one customer would not "see" another customer's products).

Not really, because things are more complicated than that.  As noted above, the integration sources aren't the entities in your domain model (see Webber's talk linked above).  Furthermore, the alignment of your persisted data into "aggregates" is an implementation details that changes over time.

Note that you will normally have only your latest domain models running, but your integration will be expected to be backwards compatible to support older clients.

Fielding

> REST is intended for long-lived network-based applications that span multiple organizations.

Comment: This is a truly excellent answer, upvoted accordingly for being helpful. I don't *quite* feel that it gives me an actual answer to the question though. Would you mind take the most appropriate (or least inappropriate) of my examples and if necessary modify it to illustrate your point? I think my answer lies in this quote "You should be choosing spellings that are consistent with RFC 3986 (hierarchy in the path, non hierarchical elements in the query string, fragments for secondary resources included within a primary."...